# PHP echo only echoes hashed passwords, and matching password to username from txt file

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble and wondered if anyone can help me. I have an assigment from school where we're supposed to create a login/register page that saves the usernames and passwords to a text file (I know you're supposed to use a database IRL but this is for the assignment). I'm having trouble with a couple of things.

First, When I try to echo $username only the hashed passwords are shown, not the usernames. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Second, I don't know how to match the username with the correct password when I'm looping for them?

Third, I don't know if I'm using $_SESSION in the right way.

I'm very new to PHP so please go easy on me.

Here's the code, thank you!:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
$anvandare = $_POST['anvandare']; //username
$losen = $_POST['losen'];//password.

$hashlosen = password_hash($losen,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (!empty($anvandare) && !empty($losen)) //If neither is empty do the following:
{
    $openlogg1 = fopen('userlog.txt', 'a+'); //open userlog.txt for reading and writing.
    $path1 = 'userlog.txt';

    if (file_exists($path1))
    {
        $userdatafile = file_get_contents($path1); //Turns the file into an string.
        $userdata = explode(PHP_EOL, $userdatafile);//first explode.

        foreach ($userdata as $userlogin) {
            $userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin); //second explode.
            foreach ($userlogin as $username) {
                if ($username == $anvandare){//Checking if username exists.
                    $usertaken = true; //if it exists $usertaken is true.
                }
            }
            echo $username . "<br>"; //only shows hashed passwords.
        }
        if ($usertaken == true){ //if usertaken is true echo "username is taken".
            echo "Användarnamnet är upptaget, välj ett annat.";

        }
        else { //otherwise write username and hashed password to userlog.txt.
            fwrite($openlogg1, $anvandare .";".$hashlosen . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }

}
fclose($openlogg1);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$anvandare = $_POST['anvandare'];
$losen = $_POST['losen'];

$hashlosen = password_hash($losen,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if (!empty($anvandare) && !empty($losen)) { //If neither is empty do the following:
    $openlogg1 = fopen('userlog.txt', 'r'); //Open userlog.txt for reading.
    $path1 = 'userlog.txt';

    if (file_exists($path1)) {
        $userdatafile = file_get_contents($path1); //Turns file into string.
        $userdata = explode(PHP_EOL, $userdatafile);//first explode

        foreach ($userdata as $userlogin) {
            $userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin); //second explode.
            foreach ($userlogin as $username) {//Checking if username exists.
                if ($username == $anvandare){ //if username equals user successuser is set to true.
                    $successuser = true;
                }
            }
            echo $username . "<br>";
        }

    if ($successuser == true){ //If successuser is true check password.
        foreach ($userdata as $password) { //Looping through password array.
            if (password_verify($password, $hashlosen)) {
                $successpass = true;
            }
        }
    }
        if ($successpass == true) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $anvandare;
            if ($_SESSION['login'] == $anvandare){
                header('Location: index.php');}
        }
        else {
            echo "Inkorrekt användarnamn eller lösenord!";
        }

    }

    fclose($openlogg1);
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

You explode each line from the file on semicolon with

```
$userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin);
```

Then iterate the resulting array with `foreach`

```
foreach ($userlogin as $username) {
    if ($username == $anvandare){//Checking if username exists.
        $usertaken = true; //if it exists $usertaken is true.
    }
}
```

At the end of that loop, `$username` will be the last item in the `$userlogin` array.

Since you're entering lines in the file in `username;passwordhash` format, that's going to be the password.

**Second**

When you use password verify, you should not be comparing two hashes. The first parameter is the unhashed password as entered by the user, and the second parameter is the hash from storage.

**Third**

You will not be able to store values in the session unless you have started it with `session_start()`.

---

What I would suggest, instead of iterating the lines in the file to find the user, is to read the file into an associative array, using username as key and password hash as value.

```
// read the rows into an array
$userFile = file('userlog.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
// explode each row
$userRows = array_map(function($row) { return explode(';', $row); }, $userFile);
// reindex the array by username
$users = array_column($userRows, 1, 0);
```

This is less efficient than checking the file line by line, but really simplifies lookups.

All you need to do to see if a user exists is to check if their username exists as a key in the array.

```
if (isset($users[$_POST['anvandare']])) {
    // user exists
}
```

And to verify the password:

```
$successpass = password_verify($_POST['losen'], $users[$_POST['anvandare']]);
```

where the first parameter is the plaintext password given by the user, and the second parameter is the hashed password taken from the file row that corresponds to the given username.

Comment: How do I compare the unhashed password and the hashed password and still loop through it?

Comment: and how do I make sure that the username entered and the password belong together and that it doesn't just find any password in the array that looks the same but belongs to a different username and log in?

Comment: Hi @Loowisa, I edited the answer to suggest a simpler approach. Please let me know if anything is unclear and I'll add further explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Don'tPanic for all your help. I wondered how you would write the if statement that begins the session and moves to index.php (I already had session_start in the beginning I just forgot to add it when i sent my code here) when using your code? I can use successpass = true now, right?

Comment: @Loowisa you're welcome. Yes, you should be able to use that now. A couple of things to note about that. You don't need to explicitly compare `$successpass` to true, you can just put it in the `if` condition directly since it's already a boolean. (`if($successpass)...`). Also, you don't need to check `if ($_SESSION['login'] == $anvandare)` since you just set it in the previous line. Neither of those things really hurt anything, they're just kind of redundant. Other than those minor points, the way you're setting the session value and using `header` to redirect look fine to me.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were asking. You shouldn't need to explicitly set `$successpass = true`. `password_verify` will return a boolean depending on the success of the verification. So setting `$successpass` to the result of `password_verify` will already set it to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic. I tried the code you suggested me but now it only echoes the incorrect username/password statement even if I log in with the right login. Any idea why? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Btw I put `$successpass = password_verify($_POST['losen'], $users[$_POST['anvandare']]);` inside `if (isset($users[$_POST['anvandare']])) {` and then if successpass == true than to go to index.php. other than that the code is the same as yours.

Comment: The problem I had was that I needed to use trim () on the hashed passwords, in case someone else needs to use this code.